# WSDL call results in 404 in ColdFusion 8

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I am calling a CFC by webservice.

```
<cfset request.remoteCFCPath = "http://www.domain.com/webservice/404_15.cfc?wsdl">
<cfset request.ws = createObject("webservice","#request.remoteCFCPath#") />
<cfset request.message = request.ws.saveRedirect(ID=form.id)/>
```

This has worked great for a long time.  All of a sudden I started getting 404 errors:

```
Cannot perform web service invocation saveRedirect.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (404)Not Found
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  404
```

I dont believe anything has changed on the servers.  I don't beleve that the 404 is accurate because if I change the access from remote to public  I get this error:

```
Web service operation saveRedirect with parameters 
{ID={{ID, 903}}} cannot be found.
```

Which actually makes sense to me since public can't be seen by remote. The Function saveRedirect returns the string true or false, no structs or anything fancy.  Obviously 404 isn't accurate since if I change it to public it recognizes it is no longer there.

I have restarted services on both machines. and cleared the web services (repeatedly) from the CF admin.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Have you tried using the `refreshWSDL = "yes"` argument to force ColdFusion to reload the WSDL file and regenerate the artifacts used to consume the web service?

Comment: Just tried it @Miguel-F, no change, still getting the 404.

Comment: What do you get if you navigate directly to the URL for the WSDL in a browser?

Comment: I see all the functions I expect to see, including the "saveRedirect" that I am trying to call.  I can call to every other function in the cfc without any problem and I can call the "saveRedirect" directly and it works as expected.  So I really don't understand this at all.